# how can i search all sound files in iphone through xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i am new to xcode programming.my need is to search all sound files and display them in table view.Any one please give me idea

Comment: Do you want to find sound files  within xcode or in Mac dir

Comment: you want to search all the sound file from your iphone device ?

Comment: Are these sound files added by you, by the user, or are you referring to the User's iTunes library, or something else entirely?

Comment: yes,i want to search all sound files in iphone and display in tabl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for Sound files within your app, Ravindra has already answered it.

If you are looking for Sound files from all other Music Apps in the iPhone, I doubt if you can access them.

You can however access the Songs from the users iTunes Music Library. You will need to use the
[MPMediaPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

Try this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-music-library-access/

Comment: Thank you roshit.Can you give any sample code for MPMediaPicker controller for iPhone.Thanks in advance

Comment: @sudheer, the tutorial has a link to download the [source code](https://mobiletuts.s3.amazonaws.com/iOS-SDK_MediaPlayer_iPod-Access/Music-Project.zip). Did you check that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can get all sound files by simply checking the extension of file.  Below I have given the example for mp3 files.  If you want to also search for another extension then simply add one more extension in the "`OR`" condition:

1. Find the `resourcePath` i.e. directory, because all sound files are resources
2. Get the list of all files in that directory
3. Now search for a specific extension in that list

   ```
   NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
   NSFileManager *filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

   NSArray *allFiles = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bundlePath error:NULL];
   for (NSString *fileName in allFiles)
   {
       if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp3"])
       {
           NSString *fullFilePath = [bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
   //do whatever you want to do with the path
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks ravindra for answering.But i am getting error at "file".can you please give me correct code.Thanks in advance